# Determining relative changes in a generic reaction

Tags: equilibrium

I'm an electrical engineer by trade and I am trying to solve a problem I found in some old course notes.

Given is a reversible, homogeneous reaction:

$\ce{ A + 2B <=> C + 3D }$

A  solution of 0.2 moles of A and a solution of 0.3 moles B are added together. The solution is lengthened until 1.0 liters. At equilibrium, 0.05 moles of C is formed. The question is to determine the equilibrium concentration of D.

How should the 'relative changes' look like? I think it's:

- $-x$ for A
- $-2x$ for B
- $+x$ for C
- $+3x$ for D

Comment: It is, but it should be rather obvious even for electrical engineers, if A,B,C,D are consider as not chemical compounds, but as whatever spent resources respectively produced items.

Comment: Thanks Poutnik. I was doubting that the small amount of A could be a limiting factor. My answer also seemed a bit 'too obvious'.

Comment: Yes, A us limiting, but it does not affect ratio of changes. But I see a flow in task  If A has initially 0.02 mol, There cannot be created 0.05 lol of C. Max 0.02, if equilibrium constant K >> 1, as it is 1:1 ratio. Can it be a typo and there is 8nitially 0.2 mol of A ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a typo.